# Is there anyway to create a link that acts just like a shortcut?

Tags: ubuntu, symlink

I have Ubuntu 14.0.4 LTS. I have the following folder on my system:

```
/opt/JBoss_4.0.4.GA/server/default/deploy
```

Also I have this symbolic link to that folder on my Desktop:

```
JBoss deploy -> /opt/JBoss_4.0.4.GA/server/default/deploy
```

When I double click on the link, nautilus opens a directory with this path:

```
/home/sasan/Desktop/JBoss deploy
```

But this is what I want:

```
/opt/JBoss_4.0.4.GA/server/default/deploy
```

Is there anyway to create a link that acts just like a shortcut? Or is there anyway to create actual shortcut in Linux?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a standard for desktop entry which is specified in [These pages](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest).
You can specify what action to take when you open (effectively click) that desktop item. The action can be bash commands.

Or in your case:
`nautilus /opt/JBoss_4.0.4.GA/server/default/deploy`

Just For the sake of completeness, here's an example:
`Chrome.desktop`

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Google Chrome
Exec=google-chrome-stable
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
Path=/usr/bin/
Icon=/home/bibek/.local/share/icons/hicolor/32x32/Google-Chrome-Google-Chrome.ico
Name[C]=Chrome
```

This is what the shortcut for chrome looks like in my Mint Desktop. That Exec line is what actually gets executed on click events, assuming the entry right after `=` is executable (arguments are separated by space).

Comment: this is command that I use for opening a current directory from command line in GUI.

Answer (score 0):

The [FreeDesktop standard](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/1.5/ar01s06.html)
defines multiple kinds of desktop entries:

> This specification defines 3 types of desktop entries: `Application` (type
> 1), `Link` (type 2) and `Directory` (type 3).

Using a type-1 (Application) desktop file is one option,
but Link-type desktop files will also work for your purposes
and is not tied to a particular file manager.
For the example given,
create a file on your desktop called `deploy.desktop`
and insert these contents:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Link to deploy
Type=Link
URL=file:///opt/JBoss_4.0.4.GA/server/default/deploy/
Icon=folder
```

It looks like this:

[image: Link to deploy]

and opens to this path in the default file manager:

```
/opt/JBoss_4.0.4.GA/server/default/deploy/
```

Note that if the path contained spaces or other special characters, it would need to be [percent escaped](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) to convert a path into a valid [`file://` URL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme).
Some [file managers](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?t=96291)
can
[assist you](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1199973/is-it-possible-to-create-a-folder-shortcut-in-kubuntu/1266060#1266060)
if you encounter difficulty doing this by hand.

Related:

- [Getting symbolic links to behave more like shortcuts in Windows](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/281986/getting-symbolic-links-to-behave-more-like-shortcuts-in-windows)
- [Is it possible to create a soft link on my desktop which opens with the target path instead of the link's path?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/310618/is-it-possible-to-create-a-soft-link-on-my-desktop-which-opens-with-the-target-p)
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/9450/is-it-possible-to-create-a-shortcut-link-instead-of-symbolic-link-to-a-folde
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028474/make-link-open-target-file-not-file-at-link-location
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/1131020/how-do-i-create-an-shortcut-to-a-foldernot-a-symlink-in-ubuntu-18-04-like-shor